# How to force a DOM element to update before others or show a waiting indicator in Svelte?

Tags: dom, svelte

I have some checkboxes that when clicked will cause a lot of changes in the DOM, and this freezes up the application for several seconds. I'd like the checkboxes to update first, and/or display a waiting indicator. I've tried different things but for some reason nothing else in the DOM will update before the freeze. The changes are made to a large table, either removing or adding entire columns, and it acts as if this has higher priority over anything else because any other attempts to update the DOM after clicking the checkbox don't go through until the table has completed re-rendering. FWIW I can use console.log to display a message before the table updates, and also after it completes for some reason.

Comment: Please provide some code / [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current logic and the ways you tried. The [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world?version=3.44.1) is a good place for building this

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {tick} from "svelte";

let checked = false;
$: applyChanges(checked);

async function applyChanges() {
  messageVisible = true
  await tick()
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      // do the stuff that causes a lots of dom updates
    })
  })
}
```

The `await tick()` applies the `messageVisible` changes to the DOM.
The double raf will wait for the browser to draw the updated DOM.